# Customizing issue fields and transitions of Mantisbt

Tags: php, mantis

I'm working on Mantisbt 1.2.8, I'm trying to customize the fields that are shown on a issue creation. until now I've been able to add fields but not to remove/hide the default ones.

I couldn't find a tutorial (for DUMMIES, jeje) step to step explanation, were is shown:
1. how to set specifically the fields in the creation of an issue and 

2. how to define a custom workflow state and transitions. 
I'd really apreciate some help.

Answer (score 2):

You can define fields and workflow states/transitions in your config_inc.php file.

As documented in config_defaults_inc.php (lots of good info in this file)

```
/**
* 'status_enum_workflow' defines the workflow, and reflects a simple
*  2-dimensional matrix. For each existing status, you define which
*  statuses you can go to from that status, e.g. from NEW_ you might list statuses
*  '10:new,20:feedback,30:acknowledged' but not higher ones.
* The following example can be transferred to config_inc.php
* $g_status_enum_workflow[NEW_]='20:feedback,30:acknowledged,40:confirmed,50:assigned,80:resolved';
* $g_status_enum_workflow[FEEDBACK] ='10:new,30:acknowledged,40:confirmed,50:assigned,80:resolved';
* $g_status_enum_workflow[ACKNOWLEDGED] ='20:feedback,40:confirmed,50:assigned,80:resolved';
* $g_status_enum_workflow[CONFIRMED] ='20:feedback,50:assigned,80:resolved';
* $g_status_enum_workflow[ASSIGNED] ='20:feedback,80:resolved,90:closed';
* $g_status_enum_workflow[RESOLVED] ='50:assigned,90:closed';
* $g_status_enum_workflow[CLOSED] ='50:assigned';
* @global array $g_status_enum_workflow
*/
```

and

```
/**
* An array of the fields to show on the bug report page.
*
* The following fields can not be included:
* id, project, date_submitted, last_updated, status,
* resolution, tags, fixed_in_version, projection, eta,
* reporter.
*
* The following fields must be included:
* category_id, summary, description.
*
* To overload this setting per project, then the settings must be included in the database through
* the generic configuration form.
*
* @global array $g_bug_report_page_fields
*/
```